# Problema node.js express-session renueva session con intervalo de tiempo

Tags: nodejs, express-session

Al recargar página en nodejs, después de iniciar sesión, esta se actualiza a undefined y después de un tiempo vuelve y se actualiza a la sesión establecida en el login, luego vuelve a undefined y despues a la sesión, en un ciclo infinito, ¿algiuen sabe por qué?

```
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'incubux',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000,
        expires: false
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion fue cambiar de express-session a cookie session y se acabó el problema
https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session